# Display hidden input value inside of Div tag

Tags: jquery

I raised a similar question to this recently, but I was completely working with the wrong code as my understanding of JQuery is still early days.

Here's the updated code I have:

```
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="numberselection">
    <script>
    var $o = jQuery.noConflict();
    $o('input[name="numberselection"]').on('input', function() {
    
})
    </script>

<div id="showselected"></div>
```

My question would be, what would I need to write in this function to display the value of the Input tag inside of the "showselected" div?

Many thanks :-)

I just need a little guidance with how to display the output of the Input value inside of the showselected div.

** Update: **

I've found this code, here on Stack Overflow:

```
$('div').each(function(){
  var textArray = $(this).html().split(',');
  var html = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
    html += '<span style="color: #12345' + i + '">' + textArray[i] + '</span>';
  }
  $(this).html(html);
}
```

Is this suitable for styling the values (numbers) which are now being displayed within the "showselected" div? I know i need to change the selector in the code i have provided above, but should it do the job? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I changed your `input type="hidden"` to `input type="text"` because the former is not a control where a user is expected to type input inside.

Anyway that part is a bit odd because it seems like you designed this whole solution just to see what a user types inside the control.. but it wouldn't make much sense since how a user should type input inside a control that doesn't show up? the `type=hidden` is meant to hold values that will be posted to the next http request with form submission and shouldn't be input given directly by the user through the UI.

Anyway after that, to change the content of an element when the event fires, you could retrieve the object triggering the event using `$(this)` inside the event handler, and you could select the target element and change its value accordingly:

```js
var $o = jQuery.noConflict();
$o('input[name="numberselection"]').on('input', function() {  
  $o('#showselected').text($o(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" name="numberselection" />
<div id="showselected"></div>
```

After the conversation we had in comments, I added a second solution that uses a setter bound to the value property of the hidden input so that everytime any js code will attempt to set its value, the function `valuePropChanged` will be invoked that will change the text shown on `#showselected`. To mimic the extension changing the value of the hidden input you need to press the button. (in this case I used vanilla javascript instead of relying on jQuery that sometimes it's really annoying because it adds complexity with no benefits).

```js
//on document ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

  //retrieves the html element being an input with the given name attribute
  const inputEl = document.querySelector('input[name="numberselection"]');

  //adds a setter/getter pair to the value property of the input element
  Object.defineProperty(inputEl, 'value', {
    valueraw : '',
    set(newvalue) {
      this.valueraw = newvalue;
      valuePropChanged(newvalue);   
    },
    get(){
      return this.valueraw;
    }
  });
})

function createSpans(valuesList){
  const spans = [];
  valuesList.forEach((o,i)=>{
    const newSpan = document.createElement('span');
    newSpan.innerText = o;
    spans.push( newSpan );
  });
  return spans;
}

//called by the setter for the hidden input for the value property
function valuePropChanged(newvalue){
  //splits the newvalue by comma and creates a span for each item
  const valuesList = newvalue.split(',');
  const spans = createSpans(valuesList);
    
  //clears and appends to the target (#showselected) a span for each value extracted from newvalue
  const target = document.getElementById('showselected');  
  target.innerHTML = '';
  spans.forEach((o,i)=>{
    target.appendChild(o);  
  });    
  
  //instead of just replacing the text of the target with the raw newvalue
  //document.getElementById('showselected').innerText = newvalue;
  
  console.log(`value of the hidden input was changed as: "${newvalue}"`);  
}

//called by the button to force setting the value property of the hidden input
function forceValueChange(){
  document.querySelector('input[name="numberselection"]').value = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
}
```

```css
#label{
  border: solid blue 2px;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: lightblue;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#showselected{
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid blue 2px;
}

#showselected span{
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" value="" name="numberselection" />

<div id="label">#showselected</div>
<div id="showselected">&nbsp;</div>

<br>
<button onclick="forceValueChange();">Mimic extension that changes the value of the hidden input</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :-) I know it sounds odd! It's because I have a plugin I am using where there is a hidden input in the background counting the user's selected choices, but I wanted to display the user's selected numbers as a reference in real-time. :) - I'll give your code a test now! Thank you again for taking the time to answer this question :)

Comment: if that's the scenario, you should be aware that the input event won't fire for an input type hidden when some js code will be changing its value. Did you succeed anyway? I see you accepted the answer already anyway you might add a so called setter to an existing property object so that a given function would be called everytime some code tried to change the value of the `value' property of an HTMLElement object. I'll add that part in case you will say something about it

Comment: Ah, I've just tried it! As you've rightly said, it's not worked! I know the input should be sufficient to show the numbers inside of the value="", but the reason why I am wanting the numbers in a div format, is because I want to style each value, which is shown in CSS) - I'm great at CSS, PHP and HTML, i'm just rubbish at JQuery.

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yeeeeesss!! Your updated answer has worked and I would of had no chance of putting that code together. It's working perfectly!! I am honestly so , so thankful! It's literally made my day, i've been challenged with this for days! Thank you :-) I'm going to update my original question with one last little question - But if it's too much messing around, it's all good - I think I might be able to manage it on my own :-)

Comment: in your further question you shared a code that when evaluated, will take every single div in the html document and will change its content (expected to be comma separated values) with a new content based on its previous one but being it represented as separated spans holding each one a value of the comma separated list. Yes it will work but it will work once when invoked only. It won't discriminate the div to process. And it's pretty unsafe to retrieve its content with `.html()` .. I would prefer using `.text()`.

Comment: For the style of the spans I suggest you use a css rule like `#showselected > span { color: red; }` for example

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I'll take your advice with sticking with `.text()` but I will have a little play to see how I can get this code working within the code structure you provided earlier! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: I included the latest bit in the solution... I hope I got it right.

Comment: I am so grateful for your help, but it appears after adding this code, I am getting this error in my console `Uncaught TypeError: null is not a non-null object`. I'm going to test my website on a different laptop, as sometimes my laptop goes a little funny with certain scripts, due to certain browser plugins I have installed :-)

Comment: Ignore that! So sorry! It's my laptop, everything is working perfect!! Can I send you some cash over for your help? I can't express how annoyed I've been with getting this code put together! I'm so happy! :-)